# ASP .NET MVC dynamically created fields not bind to FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, formcollection

I created a Partial Razor view with dynamically created fields:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < atr.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-12 panel panel-default sx-box-shadow-on-hover">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@string.Format("{0}{1}", "collapse", @atr[i].Id)" aria-expanded="true">
                    @atr[i].Label
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id=@string.Format("{0}{1}", "collapse", @atr[i].Id) class="col-md-12 panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @switch (atr[i].AtrType)
                    {
                        case "TXT":
                        case "NUM":
                            <input id=@atr[i].Id class="form-control margin5" name=@atr[i].Name type="text" />
                            break;
                        case "CHB":
                            <input class="form-control margin5" name=@atr[i].Name type="checkbox" />
                            break;
                        case "DTP":
                            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                                                .Name(@atr[i].Name)
                                                .Value(DateTime.Now)
                                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-top: 5px; width:100% !important", title = @atr[i].Name })
                            )
                            break;
                        case "WTXT":
                            <textarea name=@atr[i].Name , rows="3"></textarea>
                            break;
                    }
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Partial view is placed in other view with static fields and button. When I make POST action using button, in FormCollection I have only values from static fields. I can't bind this field's to Model because user can add or delete them in any moment. Every dynamic field created in partial view has it's own Id and Name. What am I missing here?

Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
{
    //
}
```

Main Razor Page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-md-12 panel panel-default sx-box-shadow-on-hover">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#searchCollapse" aria-expanded="true">
                    Search options
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="searchCollapse" class="col-md-12 panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-12 fontBold margin5">Document type:</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("DocumentTypesDropDownList")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetDocTypes", "Home");
                        });
                    })
                    .Events(e =>
                    {
                        e.Change("docTypeOnChange");
                    })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-top: 5px; width:100% !important", title = "DocumentTypesDropDownList" })
                )
                <button id="SearchButton" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin5">Search</button>
                <div id="searchPanelDiv">
                    @{
                        Html.RenderPartial("SearchPanel");
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Request body looks like this:

```
DocumentTypesDropDownList=1&Identificator=1234
```

Parameters from dynamic fields are missing.

Comment: can you add the `FormCollection`  content?

Comment: I can give you advice. Try to open the developer tools, send the request to the controller and check how the body of the POST request looks like, and check what fields are missing. It can help you a lot when investigating what is wrong. There might be a possibility that your missing fields are in the body but the json format is not the same as the `FormCollection`

Comment: In FormCollection i have 2 values for keys "DocumentTypesDropDownList" and "IdentificatorTextBox" which are 2 static fields from main and partial pages. That's it.

Comment: so can you edit please your question and paste the whole class then

Comment: You have multiple forms. One in the main page and as many as the for loop creates in the partial. You need to rewrite the partial so that the inputs are embedded as a part of the parent form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested forms are unsupported in HTML.

If you remove the `<form>` and `</form>` tags from the partial view you should be able to capture the dynamic inputs from the `FormCollection` that is created on the main page by the `@using (Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: That was the case. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you place this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection form)
{
    var fields = new List<(string, string)>();
    foreach (var item in Request.Form)
    {
        fields.Add((item.Key, item.Value));
    }
    // do some other stuff
}
```

in your controller, you are able to read all the fields located in your body request, no matter if they were added dynamically or not.

Comment: There is probably some possibility to create some extension method or own attribute and add `public List<(string, string) Fields  { get; set; }` to the `FormCollection` class with automatic binding but above solution is just a quick workaround to your problem. Does it fix your problem?